# Best way to install latest localized version of Thunderbird in 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, thunderbird

I need some help installing the latest Swedish version of the stable Thunderbird. I have tried the following:
1) Install thunderbird from the Ubuntu 16.04 repo, which gives me the English version
2) Download latest Swedish version from Mozilla site and extract it
3) Copy the files from 2) into the /usr/lib/thunderbird/ folder

Two problems occur:
1) Some error messages while copying files, e.g. `cannot overwrite non-folder '/usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions' with folder '...Downloads/thunderbird/extensions'`
2) TB starts fine in Swedish, but the menu bar in the top bar of the TB window is missing

Is there a better way to get the latest version of TB fully localized to my desired language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in the repository gives [two packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial-updates&searchon=names&keywords=thunderbird-locale-sv):

```
$ apt-cache search thunderbird | grep Swedish

thunderbird-locale-sv - Swedish language pack for Thunderbird
thunderbird-locale-sv-se - Transitional Swedish language pack for Thunderbird
```

You can install them as any other package with `apt-get install`.

Comment: How do I mark this issue as solved?